# ReArrange the rows and columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm trying to rearrange the value of columns and rows with some scenario, but I'm unable to do that. I tried with pivot as well.

Following are the scenario of table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, the type of query you seek is often called a crosstab query. The SQL language is not designed for dynamic column generation. However, you can build your query with static columns like so (I used a CTE to make testing easier. You could do it with a derived table of course):

```
With SampleInputs As
    (
    Select 1 As sbuid, 4216 As fac_Id, 2010 As [Year], 1 As [Month], 10 As Venting, 20 As compustion, 'abcd' As Comment
    Union All Select 2, 4216, 2010, 2, 15, 25, 'XYZ'
    )
    , FlattenedData As
    (
    Select fac_id, [Year], [Month], Venting As Value, 'Venting' As [Type]
    From SampleInputs
    Union All
    Select fac_id, [Year], [Month], Compustion, 'Compustion'
    From SampleInputs
    )
Select fac_id, [Type]
    , Sum( Case When [Year] = 2010 And [Month] = 1 Then Value End ) As [Jan-2010]
    , Sum( Case When [Year] = 2010 And [Month] = 2 Then Value End ) As [Feb-2010]
From FlattenedData 
Group By fac_id, [Type]
```

If you want to build this query dynamically, you should not do it in T-SQL. Instead, you should build the query in your middle-tier components or a reporting tool.

Comment: ok thanks, i m looking into it...